# Install driver ATI RADEON 6230

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, radeon

I had installed Ubuntu 12.10, but wanted to try 12.04, then after the installation finished I not had Unity 3D... So I remembered that when I ran 12.10, in Additional Drivers had something like "Driver Xorg" or something, but it not was experimental and was "activated" and "currently in use", for that was Unity 3D, but 12.04 don't have no one driver enabled by default and the three than are i can activate, but can't put in "currently in use", also there is one driver called "Xorg", but is experimental, and neither works, and all drivers are proprietary, but the driver by default of Ubuntu 12.10 was free (Xorg no experimental)

My question is How can i install that Xorg driver of Ubuntu 12.10 (than is not experimental and is free) in my Ubuntu 12.04?

My graphic card is ATI RADEON 6320

Sorry, my english is very bad, i am using Google Translator for write this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the ppa I use for stable GPU driver updates
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates?field.series_filter=precise

I would suggest installing 12.10, there is a new policy that will let you upgrade directly to the next (LTS 14.04) from there and 12.10 will be supported untill 14.04 is released in April 2014
12.04 just seemed out of date to me from the day it was released